# subsonic.migrations and Oracle XE

Tags: c#, oracle, subsonic, migration, oracle-xe

Probably I'm doing something wrong but here it goes:

I'm trying to create a database using subsonic.migrations in an OracleXE version 10.2.0.1.0. I have ODP v 10.2.0.2.20 installed.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="test" connectionString="Data Source=XE; User Id=test; Password=test;"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <SubSonicService defaultProvider="test">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="test" type="SubSonic.OracleDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="test" generatedNamespace="testdb"/>
    </providers>
  </SubSonicService>

</configuration>
```

And that's my first migration:

```
public class Migration001_Init : Migration {

        public override void Up() {

            //Create the records table
            TableSchema.Table records = CreateTable("asdf");
            records.AddColumn("RecordName");
       }

        public override void Down() {
            DropTable("asdf");
        }
    }
```

When I run the sonic.exe, I get this exception:

```
Setting ConfigPath: 'App.config'
Building configuration from D:\Users\carlucci\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Wum\Wum.Migration\App.config
Adding connection to test
ERROR: Trying to execute migrate
Error Message: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-02253: especifica‡Æo de restri‡Æo nÆo permitida aqui

   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SubSonic.OracleDataProvider.ExecuteQuery(QueryCommand qry) in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubSonic\DataProviders\OracleDataProvider.cs:line 350
   at SubSonic.DataService.ExecuteQuery(QueryCommand cmd) in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubSonic\DataProviders\DataService.cs:line 544
   at SubSonic.Migrations.Migrator.CreateSchemaInfo(String providerName) in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubSonic.Migrations\Migrator.cs:line 249
   at SubSonic.Migrations.Migrator.GetCurrentVersion(String providerName) in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubSonic.Migrations\Migrator.cs:line 232
   at SubSonic.Migrations.Migrator.Migrate(String providerName, String migrationDirectory, Nullable`1 toVersion) in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubSonic.Migrations\Migrator.cs:line 50
   at SubSonic.SubCommander.Program.Migrate() in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubCommander\Program.cs:line 264
   at SubSonic.SubCommander.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\@SubSonic\SubSonic\SubCommander\Program.cs:line 90
Execution Time: 379ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Andre Carlucci

UPDATE:
As pointed by Anton, the problem is the subsonic OracleSqlGenerator. It is trying to create the schema table using this sql:

```
CREATE TABLE SubSonicSchemaInfo (
       version int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_SubSonicSchemaInfo_version DEFAULT (0)
)
```

Which doesn't work on oracle. The correct sql would be:

```
CREATE TABLE SubSonicSchemaInfo (
  version int DEFAULT (0),
  constraint DF_SubSonicSchemaInfo_version primary key (version)
)
```

The funny thing is that since this is the very first sql executed by subsonic migrations, NOBODY EVER TESTED it on oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess (I'm not exactly aware about precise `CREATE TABLE` syntax for Oracle): SubSonic attempts to create a "Schema Info" table (see [this](http://subsonicproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SubSonic.Migrations/Migrator.cs), search for `private static void CreateSchemaInfo(string providerName)`) with "0" being the default value. Internally it uses `OracleGenerator` which is basically an [ANSIGenerator](https://forgesvn1.novell.com/svn/mojoportal/vendor/SubSonic/SqlQuery/SqlGenerators/ANSISqlGenerator.cs), so this might be the problem.

Comment: You are right! I did a step by step debug and could see that subsonic is using a SQL completely alien to oracle. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is my fault. I don't have a license for Oracle nor do I have the slightest clue on how it works. What I tried to do (with respect to SQL generation) was to have a base class that generates ANSI-compliant SQL (yah, I know - but a guy can dream) with virtual methods that each provider can tweak as needed.

Eric and others (who use Oracle) tested out most of the queries etc - but you're correct - we never had a chance to test Migrations on Oracle. This is my fault and I take responsibility. I need to take some time to get to know Oracle - or find a committer willing to devote more time here.

Comment: That's also you fault that subsonic exists and let's be honest, it really rocks. 
About oracle, you can download oracle express (http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html), it's the free version for development and it has all the features you need. I'll take a look on this anyway, cheers!